# How can I use localstorage to make sure a user cannot hit like more than once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-hooks

I'm trying to prevent the user from liking photos more than once when refreshing the page.

So the current **incorrect** flow is: click like on desired photo > number increments > refresh the page > `click like on desired photo > number increments > refresh the page > *rinse & repeat*`

The **correct** flow should be: `click like on desired photo > number increments > refresh the page > click like on desired photo > number decrements > *rinse & repeat*`

I know I'll need to map the liked `UserID`s into local storage so that the browser remembers which photos were liked but I'm not sure how.

One of my many, many attempts in the `else{}` block is below.  I've completely hit a wall  and not sure how to achieve this.

**Note:** using localstorage is not new to me as you can see I'm using it for something unrelated in the `return()`.  However, this mapping stuff to localstorage is what has me stumped.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    };

    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-user-uploads-data', {headers})
        .then(resp => {
            console.log(resp.data);
            setGridData(resp.data);
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
    

}, []);


const handleLikesBasedOnUserId = (likedPhotoUserId, userName) => {
    let mapOfLikes = {};

    if(userLikedPhotos[likedPhotoUserId]) {
        // dislike
        delete userLikedPhotos[likedPhotoUserId];
        gridData.find(photo => photo.UserID === likedPhotoUserId).likes--;
        handleDislike(likedPhotoUserId, userName); // Send dislike incrementation via POST request  

        // localstorage logic?

    } else {
        // like
        userLikedPhotos[likedPhotoUserId] = true;
        gridData.find(photo => photo.UserID === likedPhotoUserId).likes++;

        // attempt below
        mapOfLikes[likedPhotoUserId] = mapOfLikes[likedPhotoUserId] ?? 1;
        localStorage.setItem('mapOfLikes', JSON.stringify(mapOfLikes));

        handleLike(likedPhotoUserId, userName); // Send like incrementation via POST request

        // localstorage logic?

    }

    // Spread the userLikedPhotos to create a new object and force a rendering
    setUserLikedPhotos({...userLikedPhotos});
};

return(
  {
     gridData.map((photos, index) => {
        <span className="likesAmt">❤️ {photos.likes}</span><br/><Button variant="success" onClick={() => handleLikesBasedOnUserId(photos.UserID, photos.name)}>Like</Button><br/><span className="name">{photos.name} {localStorage.getItem('UserID') === photos.UserID ? <h6 className="you">(You)</h6> : null}</span>
     })    
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(mapOfLikes) {
         // dislikes logic
         localStorage.deletItem('mapOfLikes')
    else {
         // likes logic
         localStorage.setItem('mapOfLikes', json.stringify(mapOflikes)
```